# ideas on how to implement Like and Unlike functionality in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, facebook-like

I have an outer all posts loop and an inner user post likes history loop,this is the logic to show the button that liked my post

[this is my code logic to show the button that liked ny post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnlMa.png)

how do i know when i click that like button i will like or unlike that post and send API request to server (works like facebook like function)

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJDpi.png)

im a using vue 3,an i am a new bie,Any advice to keep my code clean,thank

Comment: Please, post all relevant code as text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question . As for the problem, you could compare the value in a watcher, but the straightforward way is to call a method where you'll know whether it's like or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.